# Plot of sin(x)/x is shifted/misplaced

Tags: latex, tikz

I want to plot `sin(x)/x` but the x-axis is offset by `\pi/2`.
The mwe is

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            % cycle list,
            clip=true,
            xmin=-4*pi,xmax=4*pi,
            %axis lines=left,
            %axis x line=middle,
            %axis y line=left,
            xtick distance = pi/2,
            xticklabels={
            % foo,
            $-4\pi$,
            $-\frac{7}{2}\pi$,
            $-3\pi$,
            $-\frac{5}{2}\pi$,
            $-2\pi$,
            $-\frac{3}{2}\pi$,
            $-\pi$,
            $-\frac{1}{2}\pi$,
            $0$,
            $\frac{1}{2}\pi$,
            $\pi$,
            $\frac{3}{2}\pi$,
            $2\pi$,
            $\frac{5}{2}\pi$,
            $3\pi$,
            $\frac{7}{2}\pi$,
            $4\pi$
            },
            ylabel = {$\sin(x)/x$},
            xlabel = {},
        ]
            \addplot[
                domain=-4*pi:4*pi,samples=4000,
            ]
            {sin(deg(x))/deg(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Example of local minima, and global minima and maxima.}
    \label{fig:Example of local minima, and local and global maxima.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

When I uncomment line 16 `%foo` the x-labels are misplaced, when I leave it there, the label `foo` is not printed but the alignment of the labels are (seemingly) correct.

I have no idea where the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually adding the labels, you could use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396298/36296 (I had to increase the width of the graph, otherwise there wouldn't be enough room to label every pi/2):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}


% Load math library, for \tikzmath
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\pgfplotsset{
    % Typeset fractions of pi at regular intervals on x axis
    x axis in pi/.style={
        % Set tick distance from style argument
        xtick distance={pi/#1},
        % Set label style: calculate reduced fraction of pi
        xticklabel={
            \tikzmath{
                % Calculate this tick's multiple of pi/#1
                int \numorig, \gcd, \num, \denom, \absnum;
                \numorig = round(\tick*#1/pi);
                % Calculate reduced fraction for \numorig/#1
                \gcd = gcd(\numorig,#1);
                \num = \numorig / \gcd;
                \absnum = abs(\num);
                \denom = #1 / \gcd;
                % Build label text
                if \num < 0 then {
                    let \sign = -;
                } else {
                    let \sign =;
                };
                if \absnum == 1 then {
                    let \numpi = \pi;
                } else {
                    let \numpi = \absnum\pi;
                };
                if \denom == 1 then {
                    if \num == 0 then {
                        { \strut$0$ };
                    } else {
                        { \strut$\sign\numpi$ };
                    };
                } else {
                    { \strut$\sign\frac{\numpi}{\denom}$ };
                    % Other style with all pi symbols same and aligned:
                    %{ \strut$\sign\frac{\absnum}{\denom}\pi$ };
                };
            }
        },
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=\textwidth,
            % cycle list,
            clip=true,
            xmin=-4*pi,xmax=4*pi,
            ylabel = {$\sin(x)/x$},
            xlabel = {},
            x axis in pi=2, 
        ]
            \addplot[
                domain=-4*pi:4*pi,samples=4000,
            ]
            {sin(deg(x))/deg(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Example of local minima, and global minima and maxima.}
    \label{fig:Example of local minima, and local and global maxima.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I think it adds an unnecessary level of complexity and does not tackle the issue that a list of 17 labels for 17  ticks is being truncated. I'll stick with providing 18 labels and loosing the first label.